# Gerrit +2 code review label is not visible

Tags: gerrit

I am a newbie for Gerrit. Just started code review on Gerrit.

For some of the repositories i am able to see **+2 code review label**

[image]

But for some of the repositories it is not visible.

[image]

Could some one please help me to identify the reason of it.

I have checked the my permission status. I have admin role.

Edit : If some one reviewed the code with +1 code review label and +1 verified, it is not showing `submit` button

Could some one please help me to understand this as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution of this we can do it by editing the project.config file.

[image]

Click on edit config button and add the give the parameters like this.

```
    [label "Your-Label-Here"]
            function = MaxWithBlock
            value = -1 Your -1 Description
            value =  0 Your No score Description
            value = +1 Your +1 Description
```

for more info please check snapshot of given file

```
[access "refs/*"]
    read = group DA-Admins
    read = group Registered Users
    forgeAuthor = group Registered Users
    label-Verified = -1..+1 group Registered Users
    create = group Pushers
    forgeCommitter = group Pushers
    forgeServerAsCommitter = group Pushers
    push = +force group Pushers
    pushMerge = group Pushers
    pushTag = group Pushers
    pushSignedTag = group Pushers
[access "refs/for/*"]
    push = group Registered Users
    pushMerge = group Registered Users
[access "refs/heads/*"]
    label-Code-Review = -2..+2 group Project Owners
    label-Code-Review = -1..+1 group Registered Users
    label-Code-Review = block -2..+2 group Change Owner
    label-Verified = -1..+1 group Registered Users
    submit = group Project Owners
[access "refs/meta/config"]
    read = group Registered Users
    label-Code-Review = -2..+2 group Administrators
    label-Code-Review = -2..+2 group Project Owners
    submit = group Administrators
    submit = group Project Owners
[access "refs/tags/*"]
    create = group Project Owners
    pushTag = group Project Owners
[access "refs/notes/review"]
    push = group Registered Users
[receive]
    requireChangeId = true
[submit]
    mergeContent = true
[project]
    description = This is a description
[label "Code-Review"]
        function = MaxWithBlock
        abbreviation = R
        copyMinScore = true
        value = -2 Do not submit
        value = -1 I would prefer that you didn't submit this
        value =  0 No score
        value = +1 Looks good to me, but someone else must approve
        value = +2 Looks good to me, approved
        copyAllScoresOnTrivialRebase = true
        copyAllScoresIfNoCodeChange = true
    defaultValue = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I set it visible by 'Repo Settings'

RepoSettings  --  Access -- Reference:refs/* -- Label Code-Review -- Allow -- select a Group or User -- Save

Ensure your account belongs to the group then can make a Code Review +1/+2